# Nullable or default value?

Tags: c#, nullable

What class should I use?

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int IdParent {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
or
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Nullable<int> IdParent {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Take into account that auto increment starts from 1 and category can be without parent category.

Comment: just depends of you, and how do you want to handle where you got no values. You will do something like if  != null, or if != defaultValue.  Just depende of the use that you want

Comment: Is there any chance that IdPparent can be NULL? In that case use Nullable! Try describe your question in more detail so we can help you out!

Answer (score 3):

If it can be without a parent, you want nullable.

To make your code more readable, you can do:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? IdParent {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

(Edit: Also, the class declaration shouldn't have parens)

Answer (score 1):

The `Nullable<int>` conveys the intent much better than the use of a default value, so I would definitely use it instead of checking for zero. It also makes the check for nullness required, whereas if you are using a default value you may forget to do the check.

In case you do decide to go with zero as a "no parent", you should define a named constant for it:

```
public class Category
{
    public const int NoParent = 0;
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int IdParent {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to use this to insert with auto increments you probably want your id to be nullable too.

```
public class Category
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? IdParent { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's more likely that ID must always have a value, but the top level categories won't have parents, so that needs to have some "no value" representation.

Comment: Usually, though if you are using this as a model for insertion with dapper and auto incremented ID field (which I do quite a bit), you'll definately want this to be a nullable int.

Comment: Most of the DB frameworks I've worked with all auto-generate the data holder classes for you.  Doesn't that one?

Comment: dapper is a micro-orb created by the stackoverflow guys. Really simple and fast: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second option, because it better communicates the fact that a category can have no parent. With the first option, you need to use a magic value to indicate a missing parent.